# Convert this Aws S3 file upload in Express to hapi Js code

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, amazon-s3, hapi.js

I am trying to implement this in hapi js 
I ma trying a particular code and seems like nothing is working i am new to hpi and this express code is working for me

````
    storage: s3({
        dirname: '/',
        bucket: 'bucket',
        secretAccessKey: 'key',
        accessKeyId: 'key',
        region: 'us-west-2',
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, file.originalname); 
        }
    })
});

app.post('/upload', upload.array('file'), function (req, res, next) {
    res.send("Uploaded!");
});```
````

Comment: can you post your hai code tried so far?

Comment: Tried to call it as a method and also tried adding as a plugin